# Hibernate unidirectonal one to many relationship giving me stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, hibernate

After a few tries, I'm having one error that I don't understand why but I think I more or less from where it comes

I have two entities, Rule and Activity.
One rule has many activities, Activity has no info about rule (yet, I have to make it bidirectional but it gave me too many errors)

if one rule has 0 activities and I update it, it doesn't gives me any error
if one rule has 1 or more activities and I update it, it gets updates but gives me an error on the return  java.lang.stackoverflow from hibernate

this is the important code of both entities

Activity.java

```
 @Entity
 public class Activity implements Serializable {

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="HINT_ID")
  private List<Hint> hints = new ArrayList<Hint>();


  public Activity() {
    super();
  //more attributes, set and getters
  }
```

Rule.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RULE")
public class Rule implements Serializable {


public Rule() {}
public Rule(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="joinedRuleActivityId.rule")
 private List<JoinedRuleActivity> joinedRuleActivityList = new ArrayList<JoinedRuleActivity>();




public List<JoinedRuleActivity> getActivities() {
            return joinedRuleActivityList;
    }

 public void addActivity(Activity activity) {
        // Notice a JoinedUserAchievement object
        JoinedRuleActivity joinedRuleActivity = new JoinedRuleActivity(new JoinedRuleActivity.JoinedRuleActivityId(this, activity));
        joinedRuleActivity.setActivity(activity);
        joinedRuleActivityList.add(joinedRuleActivity);
    }
//more set and getters
```

JoinedRuleActivity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RULE_ACTIVITY")

public class JoinedRuleActivity {
  public JoinedRuleActivity() {}

    public JoinedRuleActivity(JoinedRuleActivityId joinedRuleActivityId) {
        this.joinedRuleActivityId = joinedRuleActivityId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Activity activity;

    public Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private JoinedRuleActivityId joinedRuleActivityId;


    @Embeddable
    public static class JoinedRuleActivityId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2015726292052854803L;




        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID")
        private Rule rule;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID")
        private Activity activity;

        // required no arg constructor
        public JoinedRuleActivityId() {}

        public JoinedRuleActivityId(Rule rule, Activity activity) {
            this.rule = rule;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public JoinedRuleActivityId(Integer ruleId, Integer activityId) {
            this(new Rule(ruleId), new Activity(activityId));
        }

        public Rule getRule() {
            return rule;
        }


        public Activity getActivity() {
            return activity;
        }

        public void setRule(Rule rule) {
            this.rule = rule;
        }

        public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }
        @Override

        public boolean equals(Object instance) {
            if (instance == null)
                return false;

            if (!(instance instanceof JoinedRuleActivityId))
                return false;

            final JoinedRuleActivityId other = (JoinedRuleActivityId) instance;
            if (!(rule.getId().equals(other.getRule().getId())))
                return false;

            if (!(activity.getId().equals(other.getActivity().getId())))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 47 * hash + (this.rule != null ? this.rule.hashCode() : 0);
            hash = 47 * hash + (this.activity != null ? this.activity.hashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }

   }
```

I think this error should be quite similar to the one I had and I couldn't solve with bidirectional relationship but I don't understand whats happening here

edit.

this is part of the stack trace error I get, the rest is this repeated over and over

at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1240) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:863) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2282) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4121) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]

Comment: 1. Your association, contrary to what you describe, is bidirectional. 2. you haven' post the stack trace of th exception, but it probably has nothing to do with Hibernate, but everything to do with you trying to serialize a rule as JSON or XML. If you ask about an error, the minimum is to post the stack trace of the error.

Comment: 1. Why it is bidirectional? when I retrieve activities it doesn't has any info about rules. this is my first project with DB so I'm kinda confused about this  2. I'm gonna see if I can get the whole stack trace of the error, it was very long eclipse didn't let me see the start, and everything it showed me was about hibernate.

Comment: On one side, you have `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="joinedRuleActivityId.rule") private List<JoinedRuleActivity> joinedRuleActivityList`. On the other side, you have `@ManyToOne private Rule rule;`. So it's bidirectional.

Comment: One to many is on Rule entity, then when I retrieve a rule it has Activities info. But that many to one is only on the Id of the  joinTable so it let me  make the composite id, but the entity Activity doesn't have any attribute or info about Rule so when I  get  Activity it doesn't have any Rule info. sorry if I'm missing something.    I had a old version of the code where I had  info about rule on Activity and I had json serialization problems when retrieving rules or activities

Comment: Added stack trace of the error